# StringTokenizer breaking string on wrong delimiter

Tags: java

I am using the StringTokenizer in java to tokenize the string as shown in following is my code

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "key1@@@@@val1#####key2@@@@@val2#####key3@@@@@val3#####key4@@@@@val4###val4###val4#####key5@@@@@val5";

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,"#####");
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            System.out.println(st.nextElement());
        }
    }

}
```

**The output is**

key1@@@@@val1

key2@@@@@val2

key3@@@@@val3

key4@@@@@val4

val4

val4

key5@@@@@val5

Actually the delimiter is "#####" so why it is breaking at "###"

**Expected output**

key1@@@@@val1

key2@@@@@val2

key3@@@@@val3

key4@@@@@val4###val4###val4

key5@@@@@val5

I know i can do it by using another delimiter than ### but I want to know exact reason behind this.

Comment: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead." - [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringTokenizer` splits according to each of the characters in the provided `delim` argument.

In your case, you generate a `StringTokenizer` that splits according to `'#'` only.

From the java docs of [StringTokenizer(String,String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> .... The characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens.
>   Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens....

Answer (score 2):

In StringTokenizer you specify the characters that are going to be used as delimiters.

Your line

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "#####");
```

is equivalent to

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "#");
```

To understand the case you can do

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "#@");
```

Answer (score 2):

The delimeter is a character which is not considered as a token, so also mentioning `#` as delimeter it will give you the same output. Quoting from [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

> The characters in the delim argument are the delimiters for separating tokens. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

Hence any character mentioned as delimeter will completely be ignored and the remaining String will be tokenised.

And quoting from same source as an better alternative for your purpose:-

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Use `string.split("#####")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple delimiters to be used for breaking string, you can use the following as the example.

```
    String msg = "http://192.173.15.36:8084/";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msg, "://.");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextToken());
    }
```

More details [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/02/stringtokenizer-example-in-java-multiple-delimiters.html)